# Finding $f$ given that all roots of $x^8 - 4x^6 + 7x^6 + ax^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + dx^2 + ex + f$ are positive real numbers

Tags: roots

Assume $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are real numbers such that all the roots of $x^8 - 4x^7 + 7x^6 + ax^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + dx^2 + ex + f$ are positive real numbers. Find all possible values of $f.$

---

I'm pretty sure that Vieta's plays a vital part in here, but I'm not sure how to set it up. Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: Well, if you know that Vieta's formulas play a role, what do they say about the roots of this polynomial ?

Comment: Hint: [Newton's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities) look careful at the condition when the inequality achieves equality.

Answer (score 1):

$$  \sum_{i=1}^8 \left( x_i^2 - x_i + \frac{1}{4} \right)  = 0   $$

$$  \sum_{i=1}^8 \left(  x_i - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2  = 0   $$

each summand is zero.

In general, with Vieta
$$  \sigma_1 = \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i  $$ and

$$  \sigma_2 = \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} x_i x_j  $$
we have
$$ \sigma_1^2 = 2 \sigma_2 + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 $$
and may thus express $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 $

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how this will help.

Comment: @questionasker sorry to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the second term is $-4x^7$

$x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_8=4, x_1 x_2 x_3...x_8=f$
Since roots are real positive AM-GM will hold, then
$$\frac {x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_8}{8} \ge (x_1.x_2.x_3....x_8)^{1/8} \implies f \le \frac{1}{128}$$